# Ruby on rails - Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /essets

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

I'm working on a sales site, and added paperclip to add images to these products but however much I try I can not get this error please help me (sorry if I'm writing this wrong from Brazil)

Errno::EACCES in AdsController#create
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /essets

'(Extracted source (around line #33):)'

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @ad.save
    format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ad }
  else
```

Comment: It's likely your Paperclip configuration is wrong.

Comment: Set the directory to something you can access? Hard to say since we can't see the configuration and don't know much about your environment.

Comment: what can I do for you to help me

Comment: The issue is that you've configured Paperclip to use a directory that (a) doesn't exist and/or (b) cannot exist and/or (c) cannot be created.